# Design pattern for a client Server app

Tags: java, gwt, design-patterns, client-server, rpc

We have a client server application in GWT. The user from the client browser will be given options on provided services.

I want to send all request through a single RPC (Remote Procedure Call) method. This means I will send a string, representing the service, the server will receive this string and return the result.

Now since this will go through a single RPC request I have only the option to return to the client a single type of result and it must be serializeable (cannot return a java object).

So for example the user can want Users , the application will return a List of user objects or the user can want transactions and the server will return a List transaction objects or in the future the user can ask for an Apple and the server will return a String.

Want to gather all services and place it under a strategy or command pattern, but each service can return a different type, how can I resolve this? Or what pattern do you guys think is best?

The best thing I can come up with is have a Wrapper object that will contain all the different return types of all services, set it on the server, and get the result on the client, but it looks kind of messy.

Appreciate any advice.

Please note the server executes Java code (Servlet), so this is a Java question and the client is basically Java but with Limitations since GWT translates it to JavaScript on compile time.

Thank you.

Comment: Another way that just came up to me is to have a marker interface (e.g. Returnable) and have each return type be wrapped around the interface and casted on the client. Still seems like a code smell. Please help.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but I think you're asking a wrong question. What's the point of "send all request through a single RPC (Remote Procedure Call) method"? If you do that you lose Java (and GWT) static typing, which is one of its main advantages.

Comment: Hi thanks, not rude at all, I am just trying to design a way so I can enforce open close principle, not requiring me to update and edit the code every time a new service will be introduced. Though it might be better to just have a string sent from client, let Spring get the correct bean, place it in a strategy pattern get the results and display it on client

Comment: I guess I just haven't enough information of your domain. I think I get your point, but I can't imagine the use cases of having new services with new types and no need for new code.

Answer (score 0):

In our project, we have done exactly what you are looking for: a single RPC function which transports wrapped requests to the server, the server executes the corresponding code, and then returns the result to the client again. How much of that is smelly code -- I am not sure. But here's a brief summary of what we did:

**RPC function:**

```
public <P extends Command<R>, R extends CommandReturnValue> R execute(P command) throws SharedException;
```

where `Command<T extends CommandReturnValue>` and `CommandReturnValue` are empty interfaces extending `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable`. Every command implementation has its corresponding CommandReturnValue-implementation, which can wrap any GWT-serializable objects.

**Example CommandReturnValue:**

```
public class SaveCommandReturnValue implements CommandReturnValue{

    private String errorMessage;

    // getter and setter and other important information to return

}
```

**Example Corresponding Command:**

```
public class SaveCommand implements Command<SaveCommandReturnValue>{

    private List<String> stringsToSave;

    // other serializable fields and their getters + setters

}
```

The server-side implementation of the RPC-function then dispatches the call depending on the command-class. In our case, we have an implementation class for every command (implementing `CommandImplementation<T extends Command, U extends CommandReturnValue>`).

**Example Implementation:**

```
public class SaveCommandImpl implements CommandImplementation<SaveCommand, SaveCommandReturnValue>{

    @Override
    public SaveCommandReturnValue execute(SaveCommand command){

         // code to save whatever the command says to save
    }
}
```

We use Spring on our server-side, so it's a simple thing to register the implementation as a Spring-bean and annotate the Command with the Spring-bean-name. The dispatcher first searches the incoming command for the Spring-bean-name annotation, fetches the correct CommandImplementation-bean from the application context, and then calls the bean's 'execute' method.